# Null reference error for validation binding

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding

I tried following code but it gave null reference error for second line. I deleted second line but now it gave same error for third line. Any idea?

```
Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(txt_density, TextBox.TextProperty);
binding.ValidationRules.Clear();
binding.ValidationRules.Add(new MainWindow.Float_Positive_ValidationRule());
```

Comment: Perhaps BindingOperations.GetBinding does not find the binding you are looking for so it returns null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included the relevant XAML so it is hard to say definitively what the issue is.

If you set a break point on the line `binding.ValidationRules.Clear();` you will most likely find your binding is null, probably because there has been no binding set on the `Text` property.

If there is a valid binding set on the property then the `ValidationRules` collection should be initialised but empty (i.e. not null), so this shouldn't be your problem, which leaves the binding itself as the problem.

If you use this simple example you will see what I mean, just remove the `Text` binding from the XAML to cause the error.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_density" Text="{Binding SomeText}"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SomeText = "blah";
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(txt_density, TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.ValidationRules.Clear();
            //binding.ValidationRules.Add(new MainWindow.Float_Positive_ValidationRule());
        }

        public string SomeText { get; set; }

    }
}
```